# Why aren't my XP Mode applications showing up in the 7 start menu?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, windows-xp-mode

I did the install inside XP Mode and everything appears fine there.  The application icons *are* in the C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs location (I'm aware that per-user icons don't get ported back to 7).  What else should I be checking?

Comment: They're not under `Start-> All Programs -> Windows Virtual PC -> XP Mode Applications` on the host?

Comment: Aha!  That's where they are!  I was expecting them in the main Start menu, not hidden down under the Virtual PC menu!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, because I had to 'learn' that as well.  At least it wasn't just me. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RemoteApp program shortcuts form the XP Mode VM should be available under `Start-> All Programs -> Windows Virtual PC -> XP Mode Applications` on the host OS (Windows 7).

If you setup other XP, Vista or 7 VM's and enable the application publishing they will get their own similar shortcut folder on the host (named after the VM).